# send data from script to unity and then unity to script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to send shop_name and shop_id from script to unity, where a button is created for each shop_name. When a button is clicked it will pass that specific shop_id to script.
Note: There are many shops data and  I only need the data of button that is pressed.

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: this whole paragraph is a question

Comment: What do you mean by sending data to Unity? Giving input to your scene or ?

Comment: I have downloaded the name and id of shops from online server to c# script. Now I want to send name of all shops from c# script to unity and make button of each shop name. My problem is that when I click any button then the id of that specific shop will send to c# script

Comment: what does `downloaded [...] to c# script` and `send [...] from c# script to Unity` mean? I doubt that you store the downloaded text data into a c# script. Please add your code to the question so we can see what exactly you are talking about. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really "send data to unity"

What you can do is create component from Unity script (Create your button for instance).

If you just want to add a component to a gameObject, look at the `AddComponent` function. What you can also do is save the button you want to create as a prefab. Pass the prefab to your script as a public variable in Editor. Then do

```
var buttonObject = Instanciate(prefab); // Where prefab is the name of the variable
```

You can then place the buttonObject int your hierarchy using `buttonObject.transform.SetParent`. You can retrieve the button script by doing

```
var button = buttonObject.GetComponent<Button>();
```

Then you will be able to add events when the button is clicked usign the button variable.